# InfoPath Rule to run when dropdown is blank

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, infopath-rules

I'm drawing a blank and don't know what to do at the moment.

I have a list with InfoPath 2010 and Designer 2013 running on it.

Within the form, I have a dropdown control called Status, which by default is ***blank***, and has the following values:

- Requested
- Forwarded
- Received

**Desired Effect:**

What I'm trying to accomplish is if a user changes the Status to any of the dropdown values, then the user cannot change it back to blank.

I got confused because the default value is blank and that's where I run into a wall.

Can anyone assist in creating correct rule in InfoPath or if I need to involve Designer in this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want your DropDown should not be blank on form load?

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple validation. 
If "Status" is not equal to "blank".  Make "Status" field required. So that it can't be set to blank.